# Is it possible to globally #define a macro? (for the real-time error checker to see)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

By "macro" I mean simple values like: "#define FOO 123".

I installed VS **Code** (not visual studio), and the C/C++ and Visual Intellicode extensions.

I have a folder of a project created in another IDE which I'm still going to use to debug and more, specifically geared to certain embedded targets.
That IDE and its config code generator / vendor libraries make use of the concept of *global defines*.
(It's Eclipse based).
E.g. there are some #define's which are visible by every source file without them including any headers for it: it gets passed to the compiler as well as the IDE's "live" error checking engine.

Some of the header files that are auto-generated or come as a library from the vendor are set up such that e.g. such a global #define will select code for which concrete hardware target, out of a line of targets that's covered by the library, will be compiled.

So I open that folder in VS Code, and open a source file out of the folder.
The live error checker of VS Code underlines certain types. It can find them (Ctrl+Lclick), but they are marked as "undefined". Presumably because it has no knowledge of those global defines, and hence none of the target-specific code is enabled by its compile switch.

I found a SO question that was about adding defines to a *makefile* project, for building.
That doesn't help here, I do **not want to build** with VS Code.
I'd like the types be known to the VS Code **'live' error checker** and hence visual indicators of not-really-problems to disappear.

Edit: And of course, auto-completion also does not work for the "undefined" types, which I'd like to fix, too.

Is that possible / how?

Comment: `g++ -DFOO=123 mycode.cpp`

Comment: It's not about building, but IDE "live" highlighting behavior of supposedly unknown things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Shift+P to open the command window, then, if you installed the C/C++ extension before, there will be several C/C++ settings (how many seem to depend on what kind of sources are in the folder you opened for the workspace).
From there, you can select:**C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)**

[image: C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)]

On the then opening tab page, you will see settings like compiler path and a selection of compiler-specific intellisense modes.
Scroll somewhat below that, and there will be the Define directives box.
Easy to spot by the 3 default predefined items in there: _DEBUG, UNICODE, _UNICODE.
See yellow frame in the center of the image below.
Don't get distracted by the red box.
(sorry it's not English - but the sizes and positions of the boxes should give some orientation.)
[image: Defines]